# Is it possible to conditionally select a column value based on another column's value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, formula

I have a query where I use a CTE to get data from a huge table and aggregate values from the records and then use a query to further manupulate the data that i have. The table I have looks similar to this

[image: Table]

```
CREATE TABLE `fact_data` (
  `product` varchar(20),
  `location` varchar(20),
  `month` varchar(20),
  `sales` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `discount` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0
);
```

```
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L1','Jan',104,5);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L2','Jan',88,10);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L3','Jan',97,15);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L4','Jan',106,5);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L5','Jan',108,10);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L6','Jan',117,5);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L1','Feb',85,5);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L2','Feb',116,10);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L3','Feb',89,15);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L4','Feb',92,5);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L5','Feb',98,10);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L6','Feb',119,15);
INSERT INTO table
(product, location, month, sales, discount) VALUES('P1','L7','Feb',112,10);
```

The query I use is like this.

```sql
    WITH t AS (
    SELECT
       Month,
       SUM(Sales) as Sales,
       AVG(Discount) as Discount
       from table
    WHERE
       Product = 'P1'
    GROUP BY Month
    )
    Select * from t
```

Now, I want to get the Discount which appears in the maximum number of stores for this product in each month. The effective result I want is as follows, as I would want the sales for the Product added in all stores, hence 620 for Jan, but show the 5 as Discount since it is the available in most stores in Jan.

[image: Result]

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Can you post the results that you are getting right now?

Comment: Added queries to create and insert data. @DebjyotiSaha the response I am only able to get an avg. 
Month Sales Discount
Feb 711 10
Jan 532 8

What I need is to first find the number of locations and then get the discount available in the maximum number of locations. All this in a query. Not a function or SP.

Comment: Why is it 620 and 5 for Jan? Or 711 and 10 for Feb? Your data doesn't mention stores. Also, the reason why you should not use images is that some people use screen readers or imgur is blocked for them. How are they going to understand what your output is suppose to be? Please see the [editing help on tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Comment: I would want the sales for the Product added in all stores, hence 620 for Jan, but show the 5 as Discount since it is the available in most stores.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH Level1 AS (
    select count(*) as CountOfDiscount, month, discount 
    from fact_data 
    group by month, discount
),
Level2 AS (
    SELECT Month, Discount
    FROM Level1 
    WHERE CountOfDiscount = (SELECT MAX(CountOfDiscount) FROM Level1 AS A WHERE 
       A.Month = Level1.Month)
   )
SELECT Level2.Month, SUM(Sales) AS SumOfSales, Level2.Discount
FROM Level2 
JOIN fact_data 
ON Level2.Month = fact_data.Month
GROUP BY LEvel2.Month, Level2.Discount
```